# No module named tbb

Tags: python-3.x, pip, intel, tbb

Recently came across Intel's(R) TBB library, for leveraging parallelism in python programs, installed TBB using,

```
pip install tbb
```

and

```
pip install tbb4py
```

I make sure the pip referring to it's respective python version, but still not able to locate the module, both the packages installed successfully.

> NOTE: *using python3, with dask python module ,to test nested*
> *parallelism as per the Intel's blog,*

[unleash-parallel-performance-of-python-programs](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/blogs/unleash-parallel-performance-of-python-programs.html)

Comment: seeing the same.  also tried installing tbb via conda install and getting the same result.  wondering if there's an additional install of underlying TBB libraries that's required beyond the python packages.  Dunno.